# Why does proportionality yield multiplicitiveness and not addition?

Tags: notation, physics, ratio

I have a simple question:

Suppose that we say, quantity `y` is directly proportional to quantities `a` and `b`. This is then written as:

$$
y \propto a b
$$

Why however, is it not written as:

$$
y \propto (a + b)
$$

Meaning, how do we "know", that this is multiplicative, and not additive? Why is the former used all the time?

Thank you.

Comment: It is the *definition* of direct proportionality. There is nothing more to it than that.

Comment: @symplectomorphic what is the language used for the (a+b) example then?

Comment: you will have to (literally) read the relation in words: "directly proportional to the sum of $a$ and $b$."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two values are directly proportional if their ratio is constant. If you write $y \propto (a+ b)$ then you are saying that

$$
\frac{y}{a + b} = k
$$

where $k$ is a constant. In this situation $y$ is not proportional to $a$ or to $b$ because $y/a$ and $y/b$ are not constant. On the other hand, if you say that $y \propto ab$ then you are saying

$$
\frac{y}{ab} = k
$$

In this situation you see that (keeping $b$ fixed) $y/a$ is constant and (keeping $a$ fixed) $y/b$ is constant. So in this situation $y$ is proportional to $a$ and to $b$ as you wanted.

Comment: I see. i) So when we say that "y is proportional to (ab)", we are really making a strong statement about the model that binds y to (ab) right? (In this case, that model is that of a constant times ab). Is that a correct assessment? ii) On a related note then, what do we call it when we want to say that "y increases if either a or b increase, and decrease if either a or b decrease"? What is the mathematical name for that? Thanks

Comment: @Spacey, i) yes, and Daniel's answer also shows that if you know that $y$ is proportional to $a$ and $b$ **separately** (independently for each) it leads to the same conclusion, that $y$ is proportional to their product. ii) "increases" is not specific enough, you have to say **how** it increases - if you meant directly proportionally (independently), we go back to the answer to i).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $a$ and $b$ can vary independently of each other:

Suppose that  for some particular $a,b$ we have $y/ab =k.$

If $a$ changes  to $a'=a(1+d)$ while $ b$ does not change, the value of $y$ changes in such a way that $y/a$ does not change, so $y$ changes from $kab$ to $k(1+d)ab=ka'b.$

Then if $b$ changes to $b'=b(1+e)$ while $a'$ does not change, the value of $y'$ changes in such a way that $y'/b$ does not change, so $y'$ changes from $ka'b$ to $ka'(1+e)b=ka'b'.$

No matter how $a$ and $b$ change, the value $y/ab$ remains constantly equal to $k$.